# Basic question on c++ header file inclusion?

Tags: c++, header-files

What are the differences between below 3 programs ?. Is <iostream> a header file or C++ standard library ?

## 1.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

## 2.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

## 3.

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Second program, I have not included namespace, so what will happen ?

Comment: You will have to write, for example, `std::cout` instead of `cout`.

Comment: It looks just like a student homework... doesn't it ?

Comment: Please don't guess about the homework tag. This isn't obviously a copy-pasted homework question, and it's something that could reasonably be wondered by anyone learning the C++ language.

Comment: I don't guess: I had a *really* similar question in a test 5 years ago.

Answer (score 14):

As far as the program that is produced, there is zero difference - since nothing in the `iostream` library is referenced by the program, none of the library will be compiled in by any intelligent compiler.

When you `#include <iostream>`, you're including the header file with declarations for the `iostream` standard library. Using `#include <iostream.h>` does essentially the same as `#include <iostream>`, except that it defines all of the library's names within the global namespace as opposed to being in `std::` - it's there for reverse-compatibility with programs that used the original version of `iostream` which didn't drop the `.h`. (The `<iostream.h>` versions also often don't support wide characters, but only standard `char`'s.)

`using namespace std;` means that the default namespace for name references in the current file will be `std`, which is the namespace used by most standard library functions. While it means you don't have to prefix all of the standard library calls with `std::`, it also means that you have to be careful not to define anything that overlaps with standard library names.

Comment: Actually, I believe `iostream.h` puts things in the Global Namespace (even though no compiler under the sun actually does this). I could be wrong.

Comment: @Billy:  `iostream.h` does not exist in the C++ standard, so it doesn't actually do anything in general; one would have to specify which implementation.  It's a relic from pre-standard C++, back before namespaces, so on any given implementation that has one it probably does the same as `#include <iostream>` followed by `using` directives to export all its symbols into the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in no 3 problem with header file

The header iostream.h is a non-standard header and does not exist on all platforms. As a matter of fact it does not exist on my system (using g++ and the GNU libstdc++). So any code using it would simply not compile on my system.

The iostream.h header used to be common before C++ was first standardized in 1998. But since the 98 standard used `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`, the latter has fallen out of favor (being non-standard and all) and is no longer supported on all platforms. Code that uses it should be considered non-standard legacy code and is not portable. Books that teach it should be considered outdated and avoided.�

Answer (score 2):

`iostream` is a header file that provides declarations and prototypes that are an interface to part of the C++ standard library.

There's is, on your system, a file called "iostream" (no extension), the contents of which are copied and pasted (with recursive processing of `#include`s) at the point where you write `#include <iostream>`.

`#include` directives always pull in the contents of header files, they never add "libraries". Header files often contain declarations and prototypes that are an interface to a library, but the actual libraries themselves are attached to your program by the linker, not the compiler. When linking a C++ program, the linker will automatically attach the C++ standard library unless you tell it not to, so you don't have to worry about that.

Similarly, the `using namespace std` statement does not do the work of attaching the library. This statement only makes it so that you can write, for example, `cout` or `string` instead of qualifying them as `std::cout` and `std::string`. This works for any namespace, but is usually discouraged.

For the three examples you gave, they all give you the definitions and prototypes you need to use the iostream portion of the C++ standard library, but (2) is preferred, (1) is acceptable, and (3) is deprecated. (2) gives the additional convenience of being able to omit the `std::` prefix (at the cost of reducing the variable names available for you to use yourself), and (3) includes a different file called "iostream.h" instead of "iostream", which is usually the same thing, but the file with the .h is a relic of pre-standard C++ and so may not be supported in future compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You first two programs are standard C++ programs whereas the 3rd program uses a non-standard header file `<iostream.h>`

In 1st program `using namespace std` brings entire namespace `std` into scope.

Have a look at **[this](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html)** for more information.

Comment: The header was never part of an y C++ standard, and so can't really be said to be deprecated, which has a specific technical meaning in C++.

Comment: @Neil: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14447 clearly says that `<iostream.h>` is a deprecated header file. Also to disable the warning that we get on using `<iostream.h>` we use gcc's `-Wno-deprecated` option. Then I can't find the reason why `<iostream.h>` can't be called deprecated? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: That's devx.com, not the standard.

Comment: It's not a deprecated part of the C++ standard, but I'd argue it's correct to say that it's a deprecated feature of any given now-standards-conforming compiler.

Comment: Who cares what some random internet link says? The deprecated features of C++ are listed in Annex D of the C++ Standard.

Comment: @Neil: Yes you are correct. Managed to find deprecated features of C++ in Annex D of the C++ standard. `<iostream.h>` is not deprecated.

Comment: Fair point though about the `no-deprecated` flag. Maybe 'anachronistic' would be a better description? Ultimately though, it (`iostream.h`) just shouldn't be used with a modern compiler.